# Flex 4 descendant pseudo selectors with CSS

Tags: css, apache-flex, css-selectors, flex4

Flex 4 offers descendant css selectors and pseudo-selectors like:

```
s|DropDownList:open {
    font-size: 11;
}

s|DropDownList #labelDisplay {
    font-size: 12;
}
```

However, if I combine these two an wanted to do something like this, it doesn't seem to work:

```
s|DropDownList:open #labelDisplay {
    font-size: 13;
}
```

Is this possible with descendant pseudo-selectors?

(Of course I could use a `styleName.open` property on `labelDisplay`, but I think using pseudo-selectors is a more elegant solution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like it might be a Flex bug.

When the `:open` pseudo-selector is not already used, the descendant style doesn't get applied, as you discovered:

```
    s|DropDownList #labelDisplay {
        font-size: 12;
    }
    s|DropDownList:open #labelDisplay {
        font-size: 14;
    }
```

But, if you use the pseudo-selector; even empty, with no style information; it seems to fix it:

```
    s|DropDownList #labelDisplay {
        font-size: 12;
    }
    /* this line fixes it */
    s|DropDownList:open {}
    s|DropDownList:open #labelDisplay {
        font-size: 14;
    }
```

I can see the same behaviour in sdk's 4.0, 4.1 and 4.5. Not so pretty but at least there is a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
s|DropDownList:open, s|DropDownList #labelDisplay{
fontSize: 13;
```

}

Comment: This is not the same thing as OP is trying to achieve. The comma notation:

            a, b { /* styles */ }

Is shorthand for:


            a { /* styles */ }
            b { /* styles */ }